# Response is not available in this context in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I get the following error in ASP.net project:

> **HttpException was unhandled by user code**
>
> Response is not available in this context.

[image: Error shown]

I have tried a lot of various articles about this issue, but none helped.

Following is the code provided:

```
        protected void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
            string query;
            string userId;
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                userId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
                query = "exec usp_users_logout '" + userId + "'";
                var datatable = new DataTable();
                datatable = SQLConnection.CreateConnection(query);
                if (datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (datatable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                    {

                        Session.Abandon();
                        Session.RemoveAll();
                        Session.Clear();
                       Response.Redirect("../Login/loginpage.aspx", true);
                        
                        //Tried different code as per articles
                        //Response.Redirect("../Login/loginpage.aspx", false);
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../Login/loginpage.aspx");
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "<script> $(document).ready(function () { alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "'); }); </script>");
                        Session["Error"] = datatable.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../HomePage/ErrorDisplay.aspx", false);

                    }
                }
            }
        //}

        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "<script> $(document).ready(function () { alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "'); }); </script>");
        //    Session["Error"] = ex.Message.ToString();
        //    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../HomePage/ErrorDisplay.aspx",false);
        //}
    }
```

Comment: have u tried using server.transfer?

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik - Duh! Obviously the line which is throwing run time exception.

Comment: Is this method `Logout_Click` inside your code behind class? I mean does it inherit from `Page` class?

Comment: try using HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect in if condition

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik - And that's what exactly I said check where OP is getting the `run time exception`.

Comment: @Virendrayadav already have tried HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect  but still facing the issue